# Not able to run new react native project in Macbook air m1 2020

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Hi i am new to React Native, i have created a new RN project in the VScode.

here is the info

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
(node:92233) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
System:
    OS: macOS 12.2.1
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 86.44 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.18.0 - /opt/homebrew/opt/node@14/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.15 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.15 - /opt/homebrew/opt/node@14/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0
      System Images: android-24 | ARM 64 v8a, android-31 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-31 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922
    Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 17.0.1 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.67.4 => 0.67.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Although some other project created by someone else is running fine, but newly created is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely you find:

> Watchman: Not Found
> Android NDK: Not Found
> @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
> *react-native*: Not Found

Looks like you did not follow the recommended setup for react native.
Please go back look at the prerequisites of using RN.

Also please be aware that there are some issues with your processor, which I am not sure whether those are already resolved. I for my part exclude arm64 in xcode and run only `arch -x86_64 pod install`.

Comment: It is running successfully on Android, but not on iOS

Comment: As shared - with the M1 architecture you need to use arch -x86_64 pod install. Did you do that? Also it shows there is no watchman, I would look to get that installed.